ASP.NET FileUpload.SaveAs() Exception - The user name or password is incorrect
I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application, where I import data from Microsoft Excel file and display it in a GridView. The code has been working for more than two years without any issue, but recently it keeps failing from time to time. The code saves the Excel file temporary in a shared folder, which is accessible by a generic user account that is used to save files and access SQL database (i.e. I use Windows impersonation).
I am sure that the user account credentials are correct as I have no issue to connect to SQL database, but whenever I try to use it to save the Excel file I get an error indicating that "The user name or password is incorrect".
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // this is where I get the error, the ex.Message is "The user name or password is incorrect"
                lblUploadError.Text = String.Format("Failed to save Excel file in shared folder. File Path: {0}. Exception: {1}", filePath, ex.Message);
                return; // the system stops here because of the Exception
            }

            // this code is not reachable when the exception is thrown
            try
            {
                dtExcel = Common.importDataFromExcel(filePath, extension); // returns Excel data in a DataTable object
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblUploadError.Text = "Failed to import data. " + ex.Message;
                return;
            }

Any idea why I am getting this error (although it works sometimes)?
I tried to remove the impersonation and use my owner account (which has access to that shared folder) but I still got the same error. If I do not save the file temporary, I cannot read it to from user's local device directly to import data.

You are getting an intermittent error.  Often is caused by the Network password server not responding to a request.  When you are on a network the credentials are verified by a password server and if the server does not respond exceptions occur.  The network may be overloaded or the server may be overloaded.  There is nothing you can really do except when it happens repeat the operation that fails.

You are right, it seems the problem has been solved by freeing up some space in the network driver which was 99.7% full. Thank you for your support.

As mentioned by @jdweng, the network driver was overloaded and almost full (99.7% utilized). I freed up some space, which has solved the problem.
The error message was misleading as I thought the issue was in the user credential, not in the network driver.
